# Flowchart editor webapp (online)

Tags: gratis, web-apps, diagram

I want to draw [flowcharts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart) without having to install any software:

[image: Flowchart]

Requirements:

- Graphical: Create new elements intuitively with the mouse
- Web application, works on Firefox/Chrome with Windows/Mac/Linux
- Flowchart can be exported as a reasonably usable file format
- Free, registration does not ask for any personal info except maybe email

Comment: Either web or desktop application will be accepted?

Comment: @Shokatsuryō: I just made the question webapp-only. Offline version here: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/21129/flowchart-editor-for-windows-mac-linux-graphical-works-offline

Answer (score 5):

You might wish to take a look at **[Draw.Io](https://www.draw.io/):**

- **Graphical, to use with your mouse:** Yes. Easy drag-and-drop :)
- **Windows/Mac/Linux, same file format:** It's a web-app, so: yes (offline was not a criterium ;)
- **Free, ideally open source:** Free yes, not sure about the license

*Draw.Io* is based on [mxGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/javascript-graph-visualization-library.html), which itself is [not free](http://www.jgraph.com/purchase-mxgraph.html) – but offers its services for free. You can save created graphs to (and load them from) your local drive, your browsers LocalStorage, Google Drive, or OneDrive. The file format used is based on XML, so you could probably post-process it with your own tools. It supports a load of different graphs: the one you've used in your question is just one of many. The service includes a load of symbols and images to use directly from the page, but also offers to upload and use your own.

To give you a better idea, here are some screenshots:

[image: Draw.Io] [image: Draw.Io]
<sup>*Draw.Io screenshots* (sources: [PSWApps Blog](https://pswapps28.wordpress.com/tag/mindmapping/), [3Alternatives](http://www.3alternatives.com/3-free-google-drawings-alternatives/draw-io-2); click images for larger variants; more screenshots [here](https://www.google.de/search?q=draw.io&ie=UTF-8&nfpr=1&tbm=isch))</sup>

Btw: *Draw.Io* also allows you to export your work e.g. as PNG (plus in several other formats).

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I take upvotes for apologies (but no serials, please :) Sorry that it doesn't match your "real requirements". Might still be helpful to others, hopefully.

Comment: Looks like your answer magically became on-topic! See also http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/21129/flowchart-editor-for-windows-mac-linux-graphical-works-offline

Comment: Uh... So you adjusted your requirements to match my recommendation? Wow #D Ah, "split in two": one for online, one for offline. Yupp, good idea! And good luck with both of them! // Btw, the usual hint: Make clear in each question that there's the other one, and that it's not a duplicate because of :)

Comment: Note there is an offline version of draw.io, as a Chrome Packaged app https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/drawio-desktop/pebppomjfocnoigkeepgbmcifnnlndla