# Easy offline flowchart tool for OSX

Tags: gratis, osx, workflow, flowchart

I will prefer to using a free one, so I don't want to use visio (but if it is not as expensive as visio I am okay with a paid one).

Currently I use a mind mapping tool called [Mindnode](https://mindnode.com/). But the problem with Mindnode (and any other mind mapping tool I guess) is that it is basically a tree structure so that can't handle the situation that some child nodes will converge to one "grandchild" node, then starting from that grandchild node the new flow continues, which is quite common for flowchat.

SO can any one recommend a simple tool for that ?

---- update -----

I also prefer not using webapp (many google services are not available in China), so my question is not exactly the same as [Flowchart editor webapp (online)](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/21116/flowchart-editor-webapp-online)

---- update 2-----

I am quite satisfied with https://mermaidjs.github.io/ now

Answer (score 1):

[draw.io](https://www.draw.io/) can be used to draw flowcharts among other schematics and drawings. If you want an offline version, you can download the app at https://about.draw.io/integrations/.

I have used both the online and the offline versions for flowcharts on OSX and I can say they work quite well.